# Rails: How to write a test for the presence of all attributes in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

In a standard Rails 4.0.2 app with a model like this:

app/models/song

```
class Song < ...
  # title (string)
  # duration (integer)
  # artist (string)
  # ... imagine a lot more attributes
end
```

**How do I write a test for the presence of all the attributes?** Is there a "rails" way of doing this, because my methods seems awfully clumsy?

So far I wrote:

```
test "presence of attributes" do
  required_attributes = Song.new.attributes.keys

  required_attributes.each do |ra|
    helper = songs(:one)[ra]
    songs(:one)[ra] = nil
    assert !songs(:one).save
    songs(:one)[ra] = helper
    assert songs(:one).save
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have requirements on the attributes, you need validations.

Since you'll have validations, testing validations is enough. No need to go through all attributes in one test, which won't get meaningful things and will duplicate.

The better way is to test each validation separately. Like

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :title, presence: true
end

test "title must not be blank" do
  song = Song.new(title: '')
  assert song.invalid?
end
```

Normally I would not test those very basic things which Rails have already done. I'll only test something a bit customized at least. Anyway that depends on your style.

Comment: The only problem I have with this: the one or two lines of code `validates :attribute, :presence...` now produce a ton of test code. The ratio is so far off...Thats why I thought there was a "rails" way. However I like you reasoning and will try it out. (I'm going to wait a couple of hours before I mark your answer as correct, in case someone comes up with a better answer)

Comment: @sytycs, I understand your concern:) You can also check `shoulda` gem which will take care of those dirty works. In my memory it is for Rspec, not sure if mini test can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using assertions?

```
test "song attributes must not be empty" do
song = Song.new
assert song.invalid?
assert song.errors[:title].any?
assert song.errors[:duration].any?
end
```